# How to fix physics engine's clipping issues when modifying a mesh's shape

Tags: physics

I have an active rigid body cube and a passive rigid body plane. The cube's mesh is modified with a displace modifier and a noise texture. When I play the animation, the cube shakes and falls onto the plane as it should, but once sitting on the plane, the shaky cube doesn't bounce around despite its spasmodic animation. Instead, the deformed cube clips through the plane.

Increasing the solver's iterations to 1000 doesn't help.
How to fix this in Blender?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I believe there is a design fault in the [**Mesh Source** area](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/properties.html#mesh-source).

As we switch source to deform, the checkbox **deforming** appears.

> **Deforming**
>   Mesh shapes can deform during simulation.

That's what we need, because right now, the simulation only utilizes the cube's shape of the starting frame. Enable the **deforming** checkbox.

[image: deforming rigid bodies]

Now your rigid body simulation will respect the change in deformation caused by the Displace Modifier and update the movement accordingly. (The cube bounces.)

Even when you switch the *Source* property back to **Final** the change in geometry is respected. I'm guessing someone forgot to display the **Deforming** checkbox as well when the Source is set to final. Even though it is not shown, is value is still used.

The difference with the two option can be researched in the manual:
Deform
Includes any deformations added to the mesh (shape keys, deform modifiers).

> **Deform**
>   Includes any deformations added to the mesh (shape keys, deform modifiers).
>
> **Final**
>   Includes all deformations and modifiers.

Since the displacement modifier is a Deform modifier, you don't have to switch the *source* property to **Final**. Leaving it on **Deform** makes no difference, but has the advantage of being aware of the **Deforming** checkbox.

[image: displacement]
<sup>***Displacement*** is a Deform *modifier.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks! a lot! it looks like that was the issue, but I can't fix it in my scene, for some reason. Would you mind sharing you scene?

Comment: @Rod I could upload your scene, I literally only checked deform to make it work. There are two other things. Go to the rigid body world settings and increase the speed to 4 and the Steps Per Second to 1000. Do you see a difference now? Make sure to clear your cache.